# Sharepoint - log in form where stored procedure retrieves people's picture from server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have some strange problem in SP. When I log in to SP site where I have for example Newsfeed and some people (with profile picture) add some comment I get the login form once or more again (depends on the number of people comments) - when I click "Cancel" the images do not display but when I log in once (or more) again picture display normally.

Someone know what exactly is the problem?

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HChQW.jpg)

Comment: Small mistake in title: Sharepoint - log in form WHEN SP GET people picture from server

Comment: Are My Sites in a different Web Application? Have you added the site and mysite url to the IE trusted zones ?

Comment: Yes this is a solution of my problem. When I put mysite url to trusted zone in IE everything is ok.

Comment: Ok. I'll add this as an answer on order to allow you to check it as acepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if My Sites are in a different Web Application.

Try adding the site and mysite url to the IE trusted zones.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of authentication are you using?

If you look at your network traffic (e.g. with Fiddler) when you click Cancel on the login form, you will see that the requests for the pictures return a 401 Unauthorized.